# How to use PHP array fields for Form input search

Tags: php

i am trying to do google search from my page and the search is based on specific set of strings.
So the following code has a PHP array field with some values.
So if i need to use them when performing search ,how to do that,i tried to work on following code but it is not working.
My code is here

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <?php $fieldArray=array('fruits','gold','pen');?>
 <script>
 function searchLink()
  {
var link1 = document.getElementById("search").value;            
 window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/?q='+link1;
 }
 $(function() {
 var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($fieldArray)?>
 $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
 source: availableTags
 });
  });
 </script>
 </head>
 <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:400px;"/>
 <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"  onclick="searchLink()"/>
```

Comment: How is it not working? Do you seen any errors on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Add a sigh here The ***semicolon*** (;).

You was echo json but not **terminate** the line so its gives you

**ERROR**:-SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($fieldArray)?>;
```

Comment: how it will work without single quote around the value?

Comment: @SamiulAminShanto It's not a string, it's an array.

Comment: @SamiulAminShanto did you negative me...? and its a json so it will work bcoz it is in Bracket

Comment: OK, got it, thanks. Nop, I didn't negative. why do think I give negative your answer, just because you did?

Comment: @SamiulAminShanto its a fair game and i am getting bore in office i try to learn here and help people its just a playing avedio hage here....don't worry GoD B U